# Does KSP auto-update?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

According to the [dev team's blog](http://kerbaldevteam.tumblr.com/), KSP, 1.0 is 7 days from launch, and I was wondering, does the game itself auto-update, or do I have to manually download the game again from the website? **Please note, this question is NOT about KSP 1.0, I'm simply wondering if the game auto-updates.**

Comment: Do you have the KSP launcher or do you have it via Steam?

Comment: @RobertRose I have the KSP launcher

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [the FAQ](https://kerbalspaceprogram.com/faq.php), you have to open the patcher in the game's folder manually.

> Start the Patcher located within your game folder manually, it should be the one with the Squad monkey, if you have a Patcher file with a Kerbal icon feel free to delete it. You can also download a fresh up to date copy from the Store following the [instructions](https://kerbalspaceprogram.com/instructions.php). If you have the Steam version of the game you don't have to do anything, the Steam client will update your game automatically.

So it looks like it will **not** auto-update. That being said, I only have experience with the Steam launcher (which does auto-update) so this may be incorrect. If you have mods installed or you don't want to update right away, I'd make a copy of the entire KSP folder and store it somewhere on your computer because you generally can't go wrong with making backups.